# Parsing CSV file from DB

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have this DB dump file in comma separated CSV file with first line as heading/table name and rest of it are data and some has duplicate entry

```
HOST_#_INFORMATION,HOST#,Primary Hostname,DNS Domain,IP_#_INFORMATION,Primary IP,DNS
,11,abc,example.com,,10.10.10.10,10.10.10.1
,12,bcd,example.com,,10.10.10.11,10.10.10.1
,13,cde,example.com,,10.10.10.12,10.10.10.1
,11,abc,example.com,,10.10.10.10,10.10.10.1
,13,cde,example.com,,10.10.10.12,10.10.10.1
```

I need to print only unique columns between `HOST_#_INFORMATION` and `IP_#_INFORMATIO`. Output I am looking for is

```
HOST#,Primary Hostname,DNS Domain
11,abc,example.com
12,bcd,example.com
12,bcd,example.com
```

I tried with awk gsub option but only printing first line. how can i parse this csv file. I am open to perl option also. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
[root@test /tmp]$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{if(++a[$2,$3,$4]==1)print $2,$3,$4}' a  

HOST#,Primary Hostname,DNS Domain
11,abc,example.com
12,bcd,example.com
13,cde,example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

No need  for awk or sed, use cut'n'sort instead:

```
cut -d, -f2-4 infile | sort -u
```

Output:

```
11,abc,example.com
12,bcd,example.com
13,cde,example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input format (OP specify between 2 field but with 1 configuration showed)

```
awk -F ',' 'NR == 1{print "HOST#,Primary Hostname,DNS Domain"} NR > 1{print $2 "," $3, "," $4}' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will parse header separately from data, this is how to parse data and remove duplicates:

```
awk -F',' '{print $2","$3","$4}'|sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you could use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#NAME) module, which has rich set of functions to deal with CSV files.